# How to prevent the width of an Edittext change by the size of the text entered?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two EditText as follows:

```html
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtTxtNameReg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:hint="Name"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtTxtSurNameReg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:hint="Surname"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

As I write in edtTxtNameReg, its width increases and the width of edtTxtSurNameReg decreases.

Is there a way to keep the width of edtTxtNameReg constant and the text scrolling to the left?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `android:layout_width="0dp"` for both EditText and the width will not vary with the content

For LinearLayout when `android:layout_weight` is used the width for horizontal orientation or the height for vertical must be `="0dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Most of what Tonteria24 said is accurate, but not this part:

> For `LinearLayout` when `android:layout_weight` is used the width for horizontal orientation or the height for vertical must be `="0dp"`

The way `layout_weight` in `LinearLayout` works is:

1. Each child is given as much space as it asks for
2. The extra space is divided based on the ratio of weights for each child

It is very common to give all views in the `LinearLayout` a size of `0dp` and equal weights, or to give exactly one view a size of `0dp` and weight of `1`. This makes sense because it basically skips my first point above (the child asks for 0 width or height) and then divides the space up evenly.

However, combining `wrap_content` and `layout_weight` is perfectly valid.

**But**, it will cause different behavior. First the `LinearLayout` will give the first `EditText` enough width to wrap its content, then it will (try to) give the second `EditText` enough width to wrap its content, and then it will divide any extra space between the two views.

The result? As the width of the first `EditText`'s contents grows, the "extra" space left over to divide shrinks. The first `EditText` will eventually grow to fill the entire `LinearLayout` if you enter enough text.

So that's why setting its width to 0dp solves it for you. It stops the growing behavior. But there may be another time when you want to use `wrap_content` and `layout_weight` together, and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: I did not say that all views must have dimension = 0dp, only those using layout_weight attribute, because this was the original layout mistake, and for me to use wrap_content & layout_weight all together has no sense.

Comment: @Tonteria24 But views using `layout_weight` **do not** have to use 0dp in general.

Comment: using wrap_content and layout_weight together you are defining two times the same dimension, which is the good one ? , for me it has no sense ...

Comment: @Tonteria24 please read my answer. `layout_weight` only affects how **extra** space is divided, so it is perfectly valid to first consume some fixed amount of space. Check this image... both buttons use `wrap_content` **and** `layout_weight="1"`, and so they each have the same amount of the **extra** space. http://i.imgur.com/NkZn6I2.png